Jobs failed in airflow, despite Spark History UI jobs stuck in running. AWS Serverless
Has anyone ever experienced jobs failing in Airflow despite in Spark History UI, the jobs are still stuck in running. Also, I after I added a line of code to write the data to S3 (without reading it in any way), the jobs managed to finish. I'm using AWS EMR Serverless. That is so weird, any idea ? Is it because of the EMR Serverless ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Yeah, I've experienced the same issue. Airflow has a per task time out parameter that you can tweak to avoid it failing: waiter_countdown. Hope this helps!
